# Is it possible not to make all columns filterable in React table

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I am working on implementation filter method in react table. If I add `filterable` attribute it gives me filter input in all columns but I want not to add filter input in specific column.

Is there any solution about this?

Comment: Can you show use the minimal code to see your implementation ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a specific column to not be filterable, you can specifiy it when creating your columns like this :

```
const columns = [
  {
    Header: 'NotFilterableColumn',
    accessor: 'notFilterable',
    filterable: false  //This makes the column not filterable
  },
  {
    Header: 'FilterableColumn',
    accessor: 'filterable',
  }
]
```

So that giving the filterable attribute to your ReactTable will not make the `NotFilterableColumn` filterable :) (in other words, the column will not have the filter input)

Comment: filterable does not work for react-table v7, you have to use disableFilters: true as per @ido-evergreen answer

Answer (score 6):

To disable filter from specific columns in react table add the disableFilters options to the column. it takes in a boolean value .
Here is a code snippet below

```js
   const columns = [
  {
    Header: "Name",
    accessor: "Project Name",
    disableFilters:true
    }]
```

read more [in document](https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/api/useFilters#column-options)

Answer (score 0):

Implement your own filter logic. React-table provide callbacks for everything you need to implement it on your own:

```
onPageChange: undefined,
onSortedChange: undefined,
onFilteredChange: undefined,
```

Check props part of documentation and there are exhaustive documentation on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a solution for v8, it's relatively similar: you need to use **enableColumnFilter**.
You can do the same for sorting with **enableSorting**

```
type tableRow = {
    name: string;
    surname: string;
};

const columnHelper = createColumnHelper<tableRow>();

const columns = React.useMemo<ColumnDef<tableRow, any>[]>(
    () => [
      columnHelper.accessor("name", {
        header: "Name",
        cell: (info) => info.getValue(),
        enableColumnFilter: false,
        enableSorting: false,
      }),
      columnHelper.accessor("surname", {
        header: () => "Surname",
        cell: (info) => info.renderValue(),
      }),
    ],
    [],
  );
```